# error demo ar_pose

Tags: ar-pose

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get following error message when I like to run the demo with
roslaunch ar_pose demo_single.launch

(Link: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ar_pose):

The program 'rviz' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter)'.
(Details: serial 21 error_code 9 request_code 55 minor_code 0)
(Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
ERROR [1337029951.548533238]: Client [/ar_pose] wants topic /usb_cam/camera_info to have datatype/md5sum [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo/c9a58c1b0b154e0e6da7578cb991d214], but our version has [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo/1b5cf7f984c229b6141ceb3a955aa18f]. Dropping connection.
rviz-2 process has died [pid 4845, exit code 1].
log files: /home/janina/.ros/log/8432533e-9e09-11e1-9c66-bc7737b9bc48/rviz-2*.log

What can I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33992/error-demo-ar_pose/) by [Janina](https://answers.ros.org/users/1871/janina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-05-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello. the problem is that the bag files in the server have were made with and older version of ROS. You can use the command rosbag fix , but there still going to be some problems. Take a look [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/12252/ar_pose-artoolkit-problem/#18113), where there is a replicate of your problem.
cheers

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2012-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0